# Determine if callable can be called from class or instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

How can I determine that some method or function or whatever callable can be called as is or is it bound to an instance?

inspect does not cover all cases. I.e. is this bound to an instance or to a class:

```
PY>inspect.ismethod(object.__subclasshook__)
False
PY>inspect.isfunction(object.__subclasshook__)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell other than by consulting the documentation. There is no programmatic way to infer the author of your functions *intent*. You can always call a function "directly" from a class, as long as you pass the required arguments, consider:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def speak(self):
   ...:         print('hello')
   ...:

In [2]: Foo().speak()
hello

In [3]: Foo.speak(None)
hello
```

But clearly, the author meant for `speak` to be an instance method.

I suppose you could rule out functions with zero parameters as being callable from an instance, but that would be a highly irregular situation for a function in a class (unless it is actually a `staticmethod` object)